# Why first decision has coverage test cases better?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I'm solving a [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kangaroo/problem) and I can't understand why this solution

```
fun kangaroo(x1: Int, v1: Int, x2: Int, v2: Int): String {
    if (x1 < x2 && v1 < v2) return "NO"
    return if (v1 != v2 && (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) == 0) "YES" else "NO"
}
```

is better than this?

```
fun kangaroo(x1: Int, v1: Int, x2: Int, v2: Int): String {
    return if (v1 == v2 && (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) != 0 || (x1 < x2 && v1 < v2)) "NO" else "YES"
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "better" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in each function is not equivalent. The problem occurs when trying to flip the comparison statement below:

```
v1 != v2 && (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) == 0
```

If the complement of this result is TRUE, then you return "NO." The second solution you proposed does not actually implement the complement. The real complement is below:

```
!(v1 != v2 && (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) == 0) = !(v1 != v2) || !((x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) == 0)
```

Reducing the above result yields:

```
(v1 == v2) || ((x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) != 0)
```

I solved for this complement using [De Moore's Law](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/).

Your actual function should be:

```
fun kangaroo(x1: Int, v1: Int, x2: Int, v2: Int): String {
    return if (v1 == v2 || (x1 - x2) % (v2 - v1) != 0 || (x1 < x2 && v1 < v2)) "NO" else "YES"
}
```